# Why do I get an error when using epoll in edge triggered case inside the for loop?

Tags: c, sockets, server, nonblocking, epoll

So I have been trying to write a server that using epoll for non-blocking I/O using edge-triggered polling.So whenever I try to connect to the server using netcat, also passing the -c flag to close it instantly, I get an error from the first part of the if statement, basically the `fprintf(stderr,"epoll error")` is executed.

Can someone explain why would be the case? I thought I would be getting a "client closed connection" statement instead, but that statement is printed *after* when I connect with a new netcat command.

```
while (1) {
    printf("going back!\n");
    int nfds = epoll_wait(epoll_fd, events, MAX_EVENTS, -1);
    printf("got an event!\n");
    if (nfds == -1) {
      perror("epoll_wait()");
      exit(1);
    }
    for (int i = 0; i < nfds; i++) {
      if ((events[i].events & EPOLLERR) || (events[i].events & EPOLLHUP) ||
          (!(events[i].events & EPOLLIN))) {
        fprintf(stderr, "epoll error\n");
        close(events[i].data.fd);
        continue;
      }
      if (events[i].data.fd == sockfd) { // new connection!
        while (1) {
          // accept all the connections that are incoming on the socket.
          struct sockaddr_in in_adr;
          socklen_t in_len = sizeof(in_adr);
          memset(&in_adr, 0, in_len);
          int in_fd = accept(sockfd, (struct sockaddr *)&in_adr, &in_len);
          if (in_fd == -1) {
            if (errno == EAGAIN || errno == EWOULDBLOCK)
              break;
            else {
              perror("accept()");
              break;
            }
          }
#ifdef DEBUG
          char ip_addr[INET_ADDRSTRLEN+1];
          memset(ip_addr,0,sizeof(char)*(INET_ADDRSTRLEN+1));
          if( inet_ntop(AF_INET,(const struct sockaddr*)&in_adr,ip_addr,INET_ADDRSTRLEN+1) == NULL ){
            fprintf(stderr, "couldn't get the IP addrress\n");
          }
          
          printf("new client : %s\n", ip_addr);
#endif
          add_event(epoll_fd, in_fd, &event, EPOLLIN | EPOLLET);
          continue;
        }
      } else {

        char msg[REQ_BUF_SIZE];
        memset(msg, 0, sizeof(msg));

        if (read_all(events[i].data.fd, msg, REQ_BUF_SIZE)) {
          printf("client closed connection!\n");
          close(events[i].data.fd);
          continue;
        }
        printf("writing to client");
        char res[RES_BUF_SIZE];
        memset(res, 0, sizeof(res));
        strcpy(res, "Hello World!");

        send_all(events[i].data.fd, res);
      }
    }
  }
```

read_all is defined as ->

```
int read_all(int sockfd, char *msg, size_t buf_size) {
  printf("reading from the client!\n");
  while (1) {
    ssize_t bytes = read(sockfd, buffer, BUF_SIZE - 1);
    printf("bytes read : %ld\n", bytes);
    if (bytes <= 0) {
      if (bytes == -1) {
        if (errno != EAGAIN) {
          perror("read()");
          return 1;
        }
        // errno == EAGAIN -> there is nothing more left to ready. Exit the function
        return 0;
      }
      else {
      // bytes == 0, client has closed the connection. Leave the function
      //close(sockfd);
      return 1;
    }
    } 
    buffer[bytes] = '\0';
    printf("%s\n", buffer);
    if (concat(msg, buffer, buf_size) == -1) {
      fprintf(stderr, "buffer overflow\n");
      exit(1); // for now exit, will improve on this.
    }
    // if(strncmp(buffer + bytes - 4, "\r\n\r\n", 4) == 0) {
    //   break;
    // }
  }

  return 0;
}
```

and send_all is defined as ->

```
int send_all(int sockfd, char *msg) {
  size_t len = strlen(msg);
  size_t left = len;
  const char *ptr = msg;
  while (left) {
    ssize_t bytes = send(sockfd, ptr, left, 0);
    if (bytes < 0) {
      perror("send()");
      return -1;
    }
    ptr += bytes;
    left -= bytes;
  }
  return 0;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Form https://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man2/epoll_ctl.2.html

```
EPOLLHUP
          Hang up happened on the associated file descriptor.

          epoll_wait(2) will always wait for this event; it is not
          necessary to set it in events when calling epoll_ctl().

          Note that when reading from a channel such as a pipe or a
          stream socket, this event merely indicates that the peer
          closed its end of the channel.  Subsequent reads from the
          channel will return 0 (end of file) only after all
          outstanding data in the channel has been consumed.
```

That means you can continue to read from the socket even when epoll_wait gives EPOLLHUP.

So instead of closing the socket when you see (events[i].events & EPOLLHUP), just keep reading from the socket and close it only when read returns 0.

Comment: Ahhh thank you. I didn't know of that. Do you have any more suggestion for the above code?